Starting a new hobby advice on lenses
I’m looking at starting my journey into photography. I am spending so much time trying to figure out what to buy as a used camera and lense. I have seen some photo shops selling cameras but no lenses. I just want to know if the Nikon d3200 is a good starter option (seems to be in my budget) and what lenses would I buy for it. I have tried to understand the ‘lens’s’ language but it’s so confusing. Any advice would be really appreciated.

What are you interested in shooting? Landscapes? People? Portraits? street-style photography? close-ups of insects and flowers? Architecture? Some of these benefit from very different lenses than the others do.

Nikon D3200 was originally released in the year 2012. In its day it was considered as a good buy in its class. You may want to consider a newer model (as you are also looking for a used one) with more modern features (I noted your point on budget). Also browse this article Which lenses can be used with a DSLR camera which has no built-in autofocus motor?.

My recommendation for starting is two lenses:

A 18-55mm standard zoom lens, with image stabilization. You don't want to buy a lens without image stabilization, because all that will do is create shaken photos unless you are always shooting in bright sunlight
A 50mm f/1.8 "nifty fifty". This is a good portrait lens, and not terribly expensive. It also allows you to learn what kind of photography can be done with big aperture, and also allow shots in poor light where the subject is moving and thus image stabilization would only freeze the camera, not the subject.

Later, you will know what lenses you need. For example, if you want to take photos of something far away, you will find that the focal lengths of 18-55mm and 50mm are too short, and you will know you need a telephoto lens, either a zoom or a prime. You may also find that you like the big aperture of the 50mm f/1.8, but the framing is off, and you might want a shorter or a longer fast prime.

The Nikon D3200 is a great starter option, especially if it fits your budget. It’s user-friendly, produces good image quality, and is widely supported. As for lenses, the 18-55mm kit lens is versatile and great for general use, including landscapes and portraits. A 50mm f/1.8 prime lens is also highly recommended, especially for portraits and low-light conditions. If you’re interested in wildlife or sports, a 70-300mm telephoto lens is a good choice. Understanding lens terminology can be confusing at first, but focusing on focal length and aperture will help. Hope this helps!

Note that a 70-300mm can be used for sports only in bright daylight. It has a small maximum aperture opening. For any artificially lit situation, including indoor sports, you want 70-200mm f/2.8 for sports, AND you probably want a full frame camera too. As for wildlife, 70-300mm is ideal for anything except birds. For birds you probably want 400mm-500mm focal length if using a crop camera. That may mean a zoom or a prime.
